# Joomla: как отправить форму один раз если модуль дублируется на странице

Tags: php, joomla

На странице сайта несколько раз выводится один и тот же модуль с формой обратной связи вида

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="phoneNumber">
    <input type="submit" name="sendNumber" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Когда заполняю поле `phoneNumber` в какой то одной форме и отправляю данные, то письмо на почту дублируется столько раз сколько раз дублируется модуль на странице.

В папке модуля в файле `helper.php` функция для отправки выглядит следующим образом

```
public static function sendForm() {
    if(isset($_POST['sendNumber'])) {
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
        $mailer->addRecipient('myemail@gmail.com');
        $phoneNumber = $jinput->get('phoneNumber', '', 'post');
        $mailer->setSender('noreply@mydomain.com');
        $mailer->setSubject('My subject');
        $mailer->setBody($phoneNumber);
        $mailer->isHTML(true);
        $mailer->Send();
    }
}
```

Как сделать чтобы письмо приходило только один раз?

Comment: в вашей форме я не вижу обработчика.... куда вы отправляете данные ? или вы именно в default.php  отправляете и оттуда вызываете функцию sendForm() ?

Comment: А модуль один и тот же или копии модуля?

Comment: А в чем разница?

Comment: Поправьте меня если я не прав - обработчик наверное JS и обрабатывает столько раз эти клики, сколько форм на странице.

Comment: @stckvrw если хотите чтобы вам помогли, ответьте на мой первый вопрос